# Stop UIButton fade - Swift

Tags: swift, button

Is there anyway to stop a UIButton from doing its fade animation when its title is changed.

I am using a button to display a timer and when that button is pressed the timer is paused. It works fine but everytime the time changes the button animation kicks in and it fades and comes back to normal every second.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use a `.Custom` button instead of a `.System` button.

Answer (score 0):

This will help, although it doesn't seem to completely eliminate the animation:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
myButton.setTitle(myText, forState: .Normal)
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're dealing with a **bar button item**, you can prevent the anim with:

```
barButton.title = "New Title Here"
navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(barButton, animated: false)
```